# fetch / response.text() messes up the utf-8

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch

I am currently fetching(https://data.ssb.no/api/v0/dataset/49678.csv?lang=no) in javascript. I havent had any problem with fetching other sources so far but now I keep getting a issue with the decoding/encoding. When fetching in postman everything works fine and it returns the values "æøå". However when I try to fetch this in node it gives a question mark where "æøå" is. I have a feeling something is off with the encoding however it prints fine in postman?

```
POSTMAN
0219 Bærum (-2019)";"0000 Alle husholdninger";"2005";"Inntekt etter skatt, median (kr)";411000
VSCODE:
"1621 �rland (-2017)";"0002 Par uten barn";"2020";"Inntekt etter skatt, median (kr)";.
```

```js
async function FetchDataInntekt() {
  const url = "https://data.ssb.no/api/v0/dataset/49678.csv?lang=no";
  let dataresult = null
  const data = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8" }
  })
  console.log(data.body)
  let response = await data.text();
console.log(reponse)
}
```

The console.log(data.body)

```
<ref *1> Gunzip {
  _writeState: Uint32Array(2) [ 0, 0 ],
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    constructed: true,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    dataEmitted: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
    unpipe: [Function: onunpipe],
    error: [ [Function: onerror], [Function (anonymous)] ],
    close: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onclose] },
    finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onfinish] }
  },
  _eventsCount: 5,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    finalCalled: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 6406,
    writing: true,
    corked: 0,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: [Function: nop],
    writelen: 6406,
    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
    buffered: [],
    bufferedIndex: 0,
    allBuffers: true,
    allNoop: true,
    pendingcb: 1,
    constructed: true,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
  },
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  bytesWritten: 0,
  _handle: Zlib {
    onerror: [Function: zlibOnError],
    buffer: <Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 bc bd cd 8e a5 b9 91 a6 b9 9f ab 70 d4 4a 0d 54 cd 7c fc 27 7b 56 6a a0 0b d5 c0 74 4f 43 1a f4 3e 85 8c ca 4e 64 2a 53 ... 6356 more bytes>,
    cb: [Function (anonymous)],
    availOutBefore: 16384,
    availInBefore: 6406,
    inOff: 0,
    flushFlag: 2,
    [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
  },
  _outBuffer: <Buffer 22 72 65 67 69 6f 6e 22 3b 22 68 75 73 68 6f 6c 64 6e 69 6e 67 73 74 79 70 65 22 3b 22 e5 72 22 3b 22 73 74 61 74 69 73 74 69 6b 6b 76 61 72 69 61 62 ... 16334 more bytes>,
  _outOffset: 0,
  _chunkSize: 16384,
  _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
  _finishFlushFlag: 2,
  _defaultFullFlushFlag: 3,
  _info: undefined,
  _maxOutputLength: 4294967296,
  _level: -1,
  _strategy: 0,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kCallback)]: null,
  [Symbol(kError)]: null
}
```

What is the problem and why does it not return in utf8 like it does in postman and how can I encode/decode it to utf8? I have fetched from many other sites with no problem like this.

Comment: the response from that url has `content-type: "text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1"` - perhaps you need to process the results to convert to utf-8 if you need utf-8

Comment: I do have "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8" in the headers. I thought this would do the job? However looking at the headers in postman it does tell me that it is iso-8859-1 and yet displays "æøå". I have heard headers can be wrong and think this might be the case here with iso-8859-1

Comment: yes, you do have a request header saying the request is in utf-8, except it's a GET request, and content-type in a get request doesn't mean anything ... I was referring to the **response** header, where the server is telling you what it is sending - I don't know what POSTMAN does with responses ... those characters are representable in utf-8 and iso-8859-1, so the fact that it displays them says nothing about text encoding at all

Comment: All I want are those characters so it doesn't really matter if it is iso-8859-1 of utf-8. If they both can show them console.log() should not print question marks for them?

Comment: not sure that's completely valid - console.log in a browser, sure, but in nodejs ... what OS? what shell? what terminal program? all these can make a difference to what can be displayed on the console

Comment: I tried console.log("æøå") and that was no problem. I then tried to push insert each line from the data.text() into a database and then check it in SQL as I know have no problems with writing æøå and then I also came out as question mark

Comment: you don't seem to get it. I saved that page ... then output it to my terminal - the first line included "�r og statistikkvariabel" ... converting it to utf-8, that text now output as "år og statistikkvariabel" ... I had to convert it to utf-8 because my terminal couldn't display iso-8859-1

Comment: Oh wow, Do you have any suggestions on how I can convert it to utf-8? I now understand the problem but I need to be able to split this data and put it into data and such. So would love to find a way to convert it to utf-8

Comment: well, I saved the page as I said, then I used notepad++ to convert it ... however, since you aren't "saving the page", rather, you're using nodejs to scrape the page, you'll need to use something like iconv (or iconv-lite since you don't need the full blown iconv for iso-8859-1)

Comment: Do you know that setting content-type in the request does NOTHING at all to request a specific content-type back.  Instead, you should use the `Accept` header.  `content-type` in the request specifies the content-type of the request body (which there is none for a GET).

Comment: I changed the headers to headers: { "Accept-Charset": "text/html; charset=UTF-8" }. It still seems like it arrives in Iso-8859-1.

Comment: @Bravo Am I doing this wrong? 
`const data = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept-Charset": "text/html; charset=UTF-8" }
  })
  const buffer = await data.arrayBuffer()
  const str = iconv.decode(buffer, 'utf8')
  console.log(str)
`
I am still getting the question marks when console.log(str)

Comment: the charset used by the server is determined by the server ... if it sends using a different charset to what you need, you need to convert it, as I suggested 12 hours ago - use `iconv-lite` - it works

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for my previous code.  I have updated it and the working code is below.

```
app.get('/fetch', async (req, res) =>{

const url = "https://data.ssb.no/api/v0/dataset/49678.csv";

await fetch(url,
    {
        headers: {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"}
    }
)
.then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
.then(buffer => {

    let decoder = new TextDecoder("iso-8859-1")
    let text = decoder.decode(buffer)

    console.log(text)
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

})

I used the arrayBuffer() method and TextDecode() class

If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: This wont make any difference as the data will still not be utf-8?

Comment: I have just updated it and it is now working.  I used the arrayBuffer() method and TextDecoder() class.